# How can I remove zero values from list?

Tags: list, prolog

How can I remove zero values from the result list after the concatenation of two lists?

This is the code I've made to merge 2 lists but I'm stuck how to approach the removal of zero from the result list.

**Code:**

```
merge([], [], _).
merge([H1|T1], [H2|T2], [H2|T]) :-
    H1 > H2,
    merge([H1|T1], T2, T),
    !.
merge([H1|T1], [H2|T2], [H1|T]) :-
    H1 =< H2,
    merge(T1, [H2|T2], T), 
    !.
merge([], [H2|T2], T) :-
    append([], [H2|T2], T).
merge([H1|T1], [], T) :-
    append([], [H1|T1], T).
```

Comment: `?- delete([1,2,0,3,4,0,5],0,R).
R = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].`

Comment: Yes it works like that, but I need to implement it after merging the two initial lists , so if I have list A=([1,2,3,4,0]) ,B[5,6,7,8,9,0]), i need to clear 0 (zero) values in the return list like so R=([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]).

Comment: the you can add 2 rules that skip 0, like `merge([0|T1], Hs, Rs) :- merge(T1, Hs, Rs).` Please avoid cuts except when you really need them !

Comment: The problem statement is not very clear: you have two input lists (already sorted?), and you want to merge them (keeping the result sorted?), removing 0's from both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code takes the list with zeroes as first argument and list without as second. It works by peeling of the head of the first list: if it's a zero, the second list doesn't need it. when you hit the empty string, you're done. prolog will now backtrack and build up the second list.

`delete([],[]).
delete([0|T], L) :- delete(T, L).
delete([H|T], [H|T2]) :- delete(T, T2).`

haven't tested it but I'm pretty sure it should give you

`?- delete([1,2,0,3,4,0,5],0,R). R = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].`

Comment: In the last clause of `delete/2`, you need in the body a condition stating that `H` cannot be `0`. But I have the feeling OP is asking something different. What exactly it is difficult to tell.

Comment: @boris isn't that solved by putting the clause below the 0-case clause?

Comment: Kind of. You will have a choice point left, however, and if, for whatever reason, your predicate is backtracked into, you will start getting false results.

Comment: @Jumboman. No, that does definitely not solve the problem, it only makes the problem less apparent. It is good practise to look at (at least) the first answer**s** whenever running a query: `?- delete([1,2,0,3,4,0,5],R).` gives the following "answers": `R = [1,2,3,4,5] ; R = [1,2,3,4,0,5] ; R = [1,2,0,3,4,5] ; R = [1,2,0,3,4,0,5].` All but the first one are wrong answers!  However, preventing these is simple: using an additional goal `dif/2` in the last clause.